# Using Split function to split a string in a column into column names by delimiter on Snowflake

Tags: sql, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I am using snowflake to manipulate some data. I have a string from a csv file, delmited with '|' and I want to take this string, split it and make it into separate columns which will be used as the header of another table.
e.g. from this (i.e. if i type `SELECT 'APPLES|BANANAS|PEARS|ORANGES|GRAPES|LEMONS' FROM fruits`):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtzQJ.png)

to this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydt3g.png)

I have tried to use `split_part` to achieve this. But for some reason, my code isn't working:

```
WITH fruits AS
(SELECT 'APPLES|BANANAS|PEARS|ORANGES|GRAPES|LEMONS' AS colname)

SELECT 
SPLIT_PART(colname, '|', 1) AS APPLES,
SPLIT_PART(colname, '|', 2) AS BANANAS,
SPLIT_PART(colname, '|', 3) AS PEARS,
SPLIT_PART(colname, '|', 4) AS ORANGES,
SPLIT_PART(colname, '|', 5) AS GRAPES,
SPLIT_PART(colname, '|', 6) AS LEMONS
FROM fruits;
```

it's giving me 'Error: Invalid identifier 'COLNAME' (line 4)'

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a better way of writing this on Snowflake?

Comment: Can you try using it as `fruits.colname` all along the query like `SPLIT_PART(fruits.colname, '|', 1) AS APPLES,` and tell me; if it has any difference ?

Comment: @Tushar no. it's still giving me the same error, except with 'Error: Invalid identifier 'FRUITS.COLNAME' (line 4)'

Comment: I'm not able to replicate, works fine for me in Snowflake. Regardless, this seems like an odd way to determine your headers.

Comment: As per image, i think you may have an extra ' in the end. It may cause issue depending on your SQL syntax.  I dont know how you are running  your SQL but the SQL you mentioned should work perfectly.